# Python dataframe error : xlsxwriter exceptions : Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' and

Tags: python

I am getting Above error Python dataframe error : xlsxwriter exceptions  : Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' while running my code. Please help

Comment: please go through this before asking question [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a standard XlsxWriter exception to warn you that you are trying to use a character in the worksheet name that Excel doesn't allow. For example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello_world.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet[1]')

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()
```

Output:

```
python hello_world.py

...
xlsxwriter.exceptions.InvalidWorksheetName: 
   Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' in sheetname 'Sheet[1]'.
```